# Error in predict when using C.50 with costs and predict with type="prob" to draw ROC curves in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, roc

I'm drawing ROC curves for a series of classifiers that I've implemented. The thing is that I get the next error message in the cases when I had a C.50 classifier with a cost-matrix (I'm working with RStudio).

> Error in predict.C5.0(classifier.cost.1, data, type="prob"): confidence values (i.e. class probabilities) should not be used with costs.

The classifier is fine and when I don't use type="prob" in the predict command, it works fine too, but I don't get to draw the ROC curve.

This is the code I'm using to create my own ROC curves:

```
pred.class.cost <- predict(classifier.cost.1, data, type="prob")
perf.class.cost <- performance(prediction(pred.class.cost[,2], data$class),"tpr","fpr")
ROC.class.cost <- data.frame(x=perf.class.cost@x.values[[1]],y=perf.class.cost@y.values[[1]])
```

So two questions here:

1. What does the error mean and how can I fix it?
2. If it's not possible to fix it, any other way to create my own ROC curves? (I use then ggplot2 to get all the ROC curves and plot them together.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predict section of the [C5.0 documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf) explains that:

> When the cost argument is used in the main function, class probabilities derived from the class
>   distribution in the terminal nodes may not be consistent with the final predicted class. For this
>   reason, requesting class probabilities from a model using unequal costs will throw an error.

To get around this, let's say that you want to give more weight to the positive class, then you could oversample from the positives or undersample from the negatives (I prefer the latter). This will have a similar effect to applying a cost and will then allow you to get probabilities and generate a ROC curve.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I didn't relate that part of the documentation with the predict command... However, although I will try your suggestion to be able to generate the ROC curves. I can't (shouldn't) do oversampling or undersampling because it'll be difficult for the interpretation data (I work with health data and clinicians don't like over or undersampling, it wouldn't reflect the 'real' population, long story...). 
Is there a way to relate undersampling, for example, with the cost-matrix? Just to check if I could do an equivalence...

Comment: I think that if you oversampled by a factor of X, then that might be equivalent to assigning your positives a cost of X.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!